# AEM : getSlingScriptHelper().getService returns null

Tags: aem, sightly

I am trying to use the getSlingScriptHelper().getService in my project but it keeps returning null. I have done this in other projects and the implementation is similar. We are using sightly on AEM 6.3 in the project. My code below:

**FOOModel** :

```
  public class FOOModel extends WCMUsePojo {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FOOModel.class);

        private String foo;


        @Override
        public void activate() throws Exception{

            FOOInterface fooInterface = getSlingScriptHelper().getService(FOOInterface.class);   

        LOGGER.info("FOOInterface value is : " + fooInterface);

        }

        public String getFoo() {        
            return foo;
        }

    }
```

**FooInterface** :

```
public interface FOOInterface {

    public String getFoo();

}
```

**FOO Implementation** :

```
@Component(metatype = true, immediate = true, label = "FOO Configuration", description = "OSGi Configuration FOO")
@Service(FOOInterface.class)
public class FOOImpl implements FOOInterface {


    @Property(label = "FOO", description = "FOO to be provided")
    public static final String FOO_URL = "foo.url";


    private String foo;



    @Activate
    public void activate(ComponentContext componentContext){
        Dictionary<?, ?> props = componentContext.getProperties();
        this.foo = PropertiesUtil.toString(props.get(FOO_URL), StringUtils.EMPTY);

    }

    @Override
    public String getSsoUrl() {
        return foo;
    }


}
```

The logs show "FOOInterface value is : null".

I've tried the sling model with class injection method but it did not work either.

EDIT : I have found that the service is not active. Attaching screenshot for the bundle status. 
[image: Bundle status]

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your `FOOInterface` service is not active. You can check `/system/console/components` to see its status.

The bundle that includes that service might not be properly installed. You can check its status at `/system/console/bundles`.

Comment: Yes. That seems to be the case. What can be the possible cause of this? The other projects are working just fine with similar code.

Comment: @Vishal--JAVA--CQ, is the bundle installed? Is it active? Are dependencies met? Were there errors in the log when trying to install/activate the bundle? You'll need to debug a bit and see what's happening.

Comment: The bunlde is installed. It is active. Can't see any errors related to installation itself. Attaching the bundle screenshot for reference. 

Any hint would be helpful

Comment: Try adding some logging in your service activate method and check for errors